# How to solve issue releated to play store

Tags: dialogflow-es, android-dialogfragment, google-assistant-sdk, assistant

My app is "aquarium shop",  you will get it by saying"talk to aquarium shop' 
And by voice we are providing details like available fish details and available delivery locations
But for purchasing fish user should go to and app. So if user ask how to purchase fish then I replied to download app from play store because of this account Google not approve my action. In this situation what to do?

Your Action expressly directs users to a website, phone number, mobile app or alternative payment method to complete a transaction.

Your Action's content could not be accessed due to account restrictions or a paywall.

Thank you for submitting your Assistant action for review. Unfortunately, your action has been denied for the following:

1. Your Action violates our Transactions policies.Your Action makes an express call to complete a transaction outside of the conversation. Actions are not allowed to expressly direct users to a website, phone number, mobile app or alternative payment method to complete a transaction, whether within the Action via links or suggestion chips or in the Action’s description. For example, don’t tell a user to visit a website, Action, or physical location (or provide a linkout chip) with a call to action to checkout or pay.

In this case, after the user queries "goldfish", for example, the Action directs him/her to download the Aquarium Shop app and purchase it from there: "We have GoldFish fish in stock and you can purchase it by downloading Aquarium Shop App from google play store." Unfortunately, this is not allowed.

Please see https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies#special_requirements_for_certain_use_cases for more information on our transactions policy.

2. Unfortunately, we couldn’t find account creation / a linking prompt, although your Action has implemented the GSI account linking prompt.

If your Actions require account linking or login information, please add login credentials for a test account in the "Testing Instructions” field of the developer console before submitting your Action again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Transactions feature](https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions) of Actions on Google to enable purchases directly that way.